# Wpf add custom item in windows explorer context menu

Tags: c#, windows, menu

I am trying to develop an application which will add an extra option in windows explorer right click ( Just like notepad++, grepwin, Everything, Avast etc ). When user click the option, my application will run and it will alert (Messagebox) the selected path. I am tired searching online but I haven't found anyting yet.

[image]

**Is this possible using wpf? If not then which platform can do ?**

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with the type of program, see http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/ if you want to do that programmatically, it should be in an installer of some sort since you'll need admin rights to edit the registry.

Comment: I already check that. But I don't understand. How can I do the same process through WPF. How do I get the path when user clicked ? And What happen when user uninstall my application ?

Comment: `Environment.CommandLineArgs[1]` will give you what was passed in (the %1 parameter). You should be using an installer (like Wix), which adds your items to the registry. When it uninstalls, the installer will undo the registry changes and remove it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks but one problem. Environment.CommandLineArgs[1] returning the  the software exe file directory, not the file or folder directory use choosen. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I forgor to use %1 .

Comment: Its an array, it may be that [2] has the command argument, see the link I posted for details.